# How to config a canvas.create_text() in function in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

While learning Tkinter, I got a problem while creating a function for a button.
I need to config a canvas text in function. But I don't know how to do it.

```
canvas.create_text(700,350,font=("Arial Bold", 35),fill='white')
def clicked():
      res = "THANKYOU " + txt.get()
      res1.config(text=res)
```

I want that `res1` to be that `canvas.create_text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `canvas.itemconfig`/`canvas.itemconfigure` to change the properties of items on canvas.

minimal example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="black")
canvas.pack()
text = canvas.create_text((100,50),text="Hello", fill='white')

def clicked():
      res = "THANKYOU "
      canvas.itemconfig(text, text=res)

tk.Button(root, text="click", command=clicked).pack()
root.mainloop()
```