# How to edit text on button click in Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

I want to edit text of function `canvas.create_text()` in Tkinter. How can I do it?

I tried this code.
But it has mistakes.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Example")
root.geometry("500x500")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500).pack()

text = canvas.create_text(0, 0, text="click")

def edit():
   text["text"] = 'clicked'

click_btn = Button(root, text="Click on this", command=edit)
click_btn = canvas.create_window(0, 50, window=click_btn)

root.mainloop()
```

I don't know what must I will do.

Comment: can you share your output or error line

Comment: `text` in your example returns an object ID, to interact with it, you must use `itemconfig`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67923894.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this `canvas.itemconfig`

```
text = canvas.create_text(0, 0, text="click")
def clicked():
          res = 'clicked'
          canvas.itemconfig(text, text=res)
```

Comment: Thank you. The code is working succesfully!